# Self referring types in Python 3's type hint

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to define a parameter's type in a class such that the type references itself?

For example, the following won't run:

```py
from typing import List

class Node:
    def __init__(self, val: int=0, neighbors: List[Node]=[]):
        self.val = val
        self.neighbors = neighbors
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "node.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Node:
  File "node.py", line 4, in Node
    def __init__(self, val: int=0, neighbors: List[Node]=[]):
NameError: name 'Node' is not defined
```

Comment: please **always** use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution here is to use Python 3.7+, which adds support for [PEP 563: Postponed evaluation of annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563). All you need to do in that case is add:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

to the top of your source file, which enables deferred annotation evaluation (making your code run faster by not even trying to evaluate the annotations unless running under an analyzer like `mypy`).

Without 3.7+, you're stuck with the old [PEP 484 forward references approach](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) of using string annotations:

```
def __init__(self, val: int=0, neighbors: List['Node']=[]):
```

Note the quotes around `Node`, which defers the evaluation of the type on the assumption that it will be defined later.